# How can be string formatting method in python used for concatenating list elements

Tags: python, formatting

```
var = [‘a’, ‘b’, ‘c’]
sign = [‘=’, ‘:’, ‘=’]
value = [‘100’, ‘200’, ‘300’]

out = '<{0}>{1}<{2}>'.format(vari1, equal_sign, value)
print(out)
```

Expected output:

> a=100
>   b:200
>   c=300

But it is printing

> ['a', 'b', 'c']>['=', ':', '=']<['100', '200', '300']

Comment: `for i in zip(var, sign, value):
    print("".join(i))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> var
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> sign
['=', ':', '=']
>>> value
['100', '200', '300']
>>> print('\n'.join(''.join(x) for x in zip(var, sign, value)))
a=100
b:200
c=300
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this simpler one :

```
var = ['a', 'b', 'c']
sign = ['=', ':', '=']
value = ['100', '200', '300']
length = 3

for i in range(length):
    print(var[i], sign[i], value[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip`

**Ex:**

```
var = ['a', 'b', 'c']
sign = ['=', ':', '=']
value = ['100', '200', '300']


for i in zip(var, sign, value):
    print("".join(i))
```

**Output:**

```
a=100
b:200
c=300
```

Answer (score 1):

Using string format :

```
for i in range(len(var)):
    print('{}{}{}'.format(var[i],sign[i],value[i]))
```